# How can I send form error as a param to parent component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react. I have a form and I want to let the parent component know when I have input errors.
I tried to use the variable `myError` as a prop same as I did with `next` method but It doesn't work.

Basically when `touched.email` and `errors.email` are true, I want to make the `error` prop in the parent component true. Also `error` needs to stay in the Prop. I don't want to use State there.

Below is my child component.

I hope it makes sense. Thanks.

```
interface Props extends FormikProps<FormValues> {
    next(): void;
    myError: boolean;
}

function ErrorHandler(props: any & Props) {
   const touched = props.touched;
   const errors = props.errors;
   if (touched && errors) {
       //if this condition is true then I want to make myError true and send it as prop to the parent
       return  <div>
                <div className={style.error}>
                    { errors }
                </div>
            </div>
    } else {
      return <div></div>
  } 
}


const Step1 = (props: Props) => {
const { values, handleChange, handleBlur, touched, errors } = 
props;

return (
    <div>
            <input
                id='email' type='email' 
                value={values.email}
                autoFocus
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
            />

            <ErrorHandler touched={touched.email} errors={errors.email}/>



            <Button onClick={props.next}
                    type='button'
                    >
                    Next
            </Button>
    </div>
);
};

export default Step1;
```

This is my parent component:

```
interface Props {
    next(): void;
    myError: boolean;
}

export class View extends React.Component< Props, {}> {

    render() {
        const {
            isSubmitting, isValidating, isValid,

            handleChange: handleSubmit,
        } = this.props; 

        return (
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <Step1 {...this.props} next = {this.props.next} myError = {this.props.myEror} />       

                </div>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using redux?

Comment: I can't use redux, only mobx

Comment: `I want to make the error prop in the parent component true` props are read only so you cannot change it (only by passing new props to Parent component with specific value), more proper way would be set it in state

Comment: Also you can take a look on React error boundaries: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Answer (score 1):

Pass function from parent to child component and call it on error

```
class Parent extends Component {
  ....
  onError(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Child onError={this.onError}/>
    </div>
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
      ....
  createError(error) {
    try {
      throw "Error"
    } catch(err) {
      this.props.onError(err)
    }
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  }
}
```